# Python script works in Spyder but doesn't when converted to an exe

Tags: python, excel, exe

I've written a simple python script that uses openpyxl to read IP's out of an excel file and does a whois lookup on it and writes the results to a new excel file. Everything works great in Spyder but when I package it as an exe using pyinstaller I get an error when I run the exe.

The traceback says "**'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'values'**" like it's not reading the values from the original excel file. I've tried using the full path of the file but still get the same error. The excel file is in the same directory as the exe. Do I need to package the exe in a different way? Specifically tell it to package the openpyxl library?

I've done a lot of googling and can't find much info. Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Posting the relevant part of your code and the full error output would go a long way toward getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Actually, I think I just figured it out. I had an old version of openpyxl installed. I installed the newest version, packaged it into an exe and it works just fine! Sorry for the unneeded post and thank you for the reply!